# In jsRender, how can you access element you're updating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I'm using jsRender for the first time and I can't find much in the way of full documentation.

I'm populating a grid using this template -

```
<script id="my-grid" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="grid-item">
         <img class="grid-item-image" src="img.gif" />
         <div class="grid-item-description">{{clean:Name}}</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have a converter set up to clean up the data coming back in `Name` -

```
$.views
    .converters({
        clean: function (x) {
            if (x) {
                x=x.replace(/<br \/>/gi, " - ");
            } else {
                x="";
            }
            return x;
        }
    });
```

The converter is working fine, but what I'd like to do is actually remove this instance of the element `grid-item-description` in the `else` (when there is no text to display).

How do I find out which element I'm currently in within jsRender to remove that element?

Thanks!
- Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can find examples on this page:
http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/demos.html

The example that you need for your question is this one:
http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/04_if-else-tag.html

What you need to do is surround element with if tag:

```
<script id="my-grid" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{if Name}}
    <div class="grid-item">
         <img class="grid-item-image" src="img.gif" />
        <div class="grid-item-description">{{clean:Name}}</div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

You even don't need `else` condition in your function.

Working example of this can be found on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YT49p/)